# Fancybox, como redireccionar despues de un Submit

Tags: php, html, post

Necesito ayuda con Fancybox, no comprendo como hacer que el LigtBox se cierre y redireccione el navegador completo a otro sitio luego de un POST desde un botón Submit.

Aca les dejo el codigo

```js
  <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.fancybox').fancybox();
                $("#licencia").click(function() {
                $.fancybox.open({
                    href : 'licencia.html',
                    type : 'iframe',
                    padding : 5
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: puedes hacer eso en el PHP una vez haya hecho su cometido, o con ajax y si el resultado devuelto es el esperado, redirigir al usuario mediante javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agrega esto :

```
window.location.replace("http://pt.stackoverflow.com");
```